# Saving objects in array back to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, caching, instagram

I'm trying to filter out some unwanted Instagram images based on a review score that is a part of the photo caption.

I'm using the [Instagram PHP API by cosenary](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) for it and I have the data, and I have been able to filter out the entries with the correct syntax for a review score (*/10).

The problem is trying to get the objects back into json form so I can cache it so I dont have to keep making a million requests to Instagram.

I am trying to store the objects in an array and then encode the array back to json, but I keep getting the error in

```
 Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/***/Sites/instagram/index.php on line 16
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php 

require_once('instagram.class.php');

$app_key = '<removed>';
$instagram = new Instagram($app_key);
$media = $instagram->getTagMedia('kittens');
$pattern = '/\d+\/+10/';
$fulldata = array();

if($media) {
    do {
        foreach ($media->data as $entry) {

            if(is_object($entry) && preg_match($pattern, $entry->caption->text)) {
                $fulldata[] = $entry;
            }
        }
    } while ($media = $instagram->pagination($media));
}

?>

<pre>
    <? echo json_encode($fulldata); ?>
</pre>
```

I'm not sure if that `is_object($entry)` does much.

Comment: Maybe `$entry->caption` is not an object?  `var_dump($entry)`

Comment: I'm successfully filtering out the data. Var dumping $entry gives me what I need. Its just converting the `$fulldata` array back to json for me.

Comment: You need to post the `var_dump`, the error seems to be the `$entry->caption->text`, also the echo of the JSON.  Nobody can help without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<?php 

require_once('instagram.php');

$app_key = '';
$instagram = new Instagram($app_key);
$media = $instagram->getTagMedia('cats');
$pattern = '/\d+\/+10/';
$fulldata = array();
if($media) {
  do {
    foreach ($media->data as $entry) {
      $text = $entry->caption->text;

      if(preg_match($pattern, $text)) {
        $fulldata[] = $entry;
      }
    }
  } while ($media = $instagram->pagination($media));
}

?>

<pre>
    <? echo json_encode($fulldata); ?>
</pre>
```